# Python Class with Arbitrary number of Attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have this exercise that I worked on and it worked perfectly. This is it:

```py
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
    def describe_restaurant():
        print("The name of the restaurant is " + self.restaurant_name)
        print("Our food menu specializes in " + self.cuisine_type)

restaurant_1 = Restaurant("See Food", "Soul Food")
restaurant_1.describe_restaurant()
```

But, what if the restaurant serves different cuisine types. How do I go about it?

I know I can make the cuisine_type attribute collect an arbitrary number of arguments using (*). But how do I output it in the `describe_restaurant()` method?

Comment: For some reason, the main code is not indenting. Please bear with me..

Comment: Could you supply a list of strings for `cuisine_type`? eg `restaurant_1 = Restaurant("See Food", ["Soul Food", "Tapas", "Chinese"])`

Comment: Your code has  `self` missing in  `def describe_restaurant(self):`. Corrected in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use code along the lines of:

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, *cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("The name of the restaurant is " + self.restaurant_name)
        txt = ' and '.join(self.cuisine_type)
        print("Our food menu specializes in " + txt)

restaurant_1 = Restaurant("See Food", "Soul Food", "Vegan")
restaurant_1.describe_restaurant()
```

prints

```
The name of the restaurant is See Food
Our food menu specializes in Soul Food and Vegan
```

alternatively to access the individual types you could use within the method code:

```
for food in self.cuisine_type:
    print(food)
```